# Are there different shitos for when fasts end? What are they?

Tags: shabbat, fast-days, zemanim

Are there different shitos for when fasts end? (Similar Motzei Shabbos, when some people wait 72 minutes past shkiya to do melacha, where other people wait less.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29955

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people that wait Motzei Shabbos for 72 do not always wait 72 by a fast. The Shaalos U'Tshivos Divrei Yatziv (Klausenberger Rebbe Zatzal) Orach Chaim Chelek 2 Siman 230 writes that on a fast day you can break the fast after 60 minutes. However he says that on Tisha B'Av you should still wait till 72. The Igros Moshe in Orach Chaim Chelek 4 Siman 10 says that you can break your fast after 50 minutes and if necessary as early as 41 minutes after Shkia. So the answer is yes, there are different Shittos regarding how long to fast.

Comment: What are those shittos? (I just need the major ones - times and posek name please.)

Comment: Great answer! Do you know if your list is conclusive, or are there other shittos as well?

Comment: I think those shitot are also dependent on geography.

Answer (score 7):

You will find the info here
[MyZmanim](http://www.myzmanim.com/messagebox.aspx?messageid=sources)

Comment: Namely R' Tukachinsky permits breaking the fact earlier, and Rav Moshe Feinstein presents two opinions, one for those who find fasting difficult and another for those who do not.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen - Why should the halacha differ for people who find it difficult?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Because aside from YK, they are rabbinic, and rabbis are lenient in cases of pain/suffering.