# Disparate Zemanim in the same local community

Tags: zemanim, tisha-bav, communities, machlokes

Someone pointed out on a local email list that the ending time for Tish'ah BeAv is listed differently - significantly so - at various institutions in our local community.  He noted the following times published:

Large Orthodox A and Large Orthodox B 9:20

Chabad 9:08

Sephardic 8:55

According to the Orthodox Union, none of the above times is even close (within a minute or two) of the Zemanim I would expect:

Tzeis 42 Minutes    9:14 P
Tzeis 72 Minutes    9:44 P

The closest is Chabad, which is posting a time 6 minutes earlier than the earliest time listed at the OU. Furthermore, the differences in times seem to only occur on fast days; this year's 9 Av schedule appears, to me, to have the most widely divergent times published here.

What accounts for this disparity?  What formula(e) might these organizations be using that they disagree so markedly?

Comment: [From Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/134527/jewish/About-Zmanim.htm), "There are differing opinions when Tzeit Hakochavim takes place. Out of consideration for people's comfort, and considering that the fast days are rabbinic decree, not Torah law, we rely on a slightly earlier opinion concerning the end of day fasts (aside for Yom Kippur)." A and B are probably going by their usual opinion for tzeit hakochavim.

Comment: see myzmanim's explanations of the different times to calculate Tzeit: http://www.myzmanim.com/messagebox.aspx?messageid=sources

Comment: @Daniel, you may be correct, but what about the sephardic time?

Comment: @Menachem, I've seen it, but note that NONE of the times agrees with the OU, for example, and that the divergence only occurs on occasion. See my newest edit.

Comment: How bright are the three stars that you wait for.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3770

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific as to which location and then someone can see whether the Zemanim are sensible.

Comment: There are different ways to calculate and sometimes some methods of calculation are just incorrect. If you let us know your location we can try to check it out.

Comment: Dear OP:  If you have an Android phone or tablet, try using the free [Halachic Times](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sf.times&hl=en) app.  It uses the Java Zmanim API, and so can calculate nightfall according to about two dozen different opinions.  (Note that, as the MyZmanim website points out, some of the opinions shown apply only in specific situations and are not intended for general use. Please do not rely on any of those zmanim without consulting a qualified Rav.)